# Access to mysql server from external network (xampp)

Tags: mysql, networking, phpmyadmin, xampp

I downloaded xampp and made it work(mysql, phpmyadmin) in internal network.
Now I want to make it accessed from external network ,But I want only the mysql server to be external accessed and phpmyadmin only internal.

How can I do it? port 80 / 8080 is already in use in router so I need to use another ports , does it matter?

Comment: Have you got access to computer where ur sql server is running?

Comment: @koviroli Yes I have access to computer ,I can access phpmyadmin inside LAN.(Inbound Rules)

Comment: For external access download MySQL Workbench and connect. Make sure port 3306 is opened and `skip-networking` is commented out

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open up port 80 on your router. go to the port forwarding setting and  make the external port 80 if you just want to type in your ip address when connecting to your computer. Otherwise, change the port to whatever you want and set the internal port to 80.